# How do you reverse list items

Tags: html, asp.net

Is any easy way to reverse the following lines of code in asp.net?

For example:

```
<li><a href="#about" class="scroll-to">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#service" class="scroll-to">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll-to">Portfolio</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll-to">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#service" class="scroll-to">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" class="scroll-to">About</a></li>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here??

Comment: It just sample. I have huge code that I want to invert them. Im looking for easy way for. like Shortcut key or somthing like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this using jquery:

```
$("li").get().reverse()
```

[FiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/UT3Jd/)

Comment: though this would work, if you have 400 options visible to user at once then I guess you need to think over your design again